# Почему не выполнятся if(isset) который в if а тот в if(isset)

Tags: post, php, if

```
if(isset($_POST['redgr'])or die(mysql_error()))
        {   
    $g1=$_POST['group'];    
    $g2=$_POST["дисциплина"];
    $g3=$_POST['vlec'];
    if($g3==on)
        {
                echo "Сколько ?<input type='text' name='collec' >
                <input type='submit' name='adcollec'>";}

                if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))
                    {   
                        $acol=$_POST['collec'];
                        echo count($acol). "ONO<br>";   
            }
}
```

не реагирует =(

```
if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))
                        {   
                            $acol=$_POST['collec'];
                            echo count($acol). "ONO<br>";   
                }
```

Comment: Если правильно понял, когда проверяется условие

    if(isset($_POST['adcollec'])),

пользователь еще не нажал кнопочку. Когда он нажал эту кнопочку, то условие

    if($g3==on)

или условие

    isset($_POST['redgr'])

не срабатывает, потому до нужной проверки дело не доходит. Я прав?

До каждого условия и после него сделайте вывод. Например, пронумеруйте каждое условие, до него выводите "{$num} BEFORE", после "{$num} AFTER". И посмотрите на каком моменте все ломается.

Если ломается все-таки на

    if(isset($_POST['adcollec']))

то проверьте массив $_POST - значит что-то там не то...

Comment: @научите, ну так либо ``=='on'``, либо ``==$on``, либо где-то ``define('on', '???');``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала, почему одно из названий переменных на кириллице?
if(isset($_POST['redgr'])or die(mysql_error())) — неверная конструкция. Какой mysql_error() вы ожидаете, если проверяете наличие переменной в $_POST массиве?